# Pedir que se rellene un campo c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, textbox

Bueno pasa lo siguiente estoy intentando que se pida un campo por si esta en blanco

tengo lo siguiente ,tengo un textbox con nombre txtEdad

entonces lo pongo asi

```
int edad=Int32.Parse(txtEdad.Text);

if(txtEdad.Text=="")
{
  MessageBox.Show("Debes rellenar este campo");
}
```

Pero cuando lo pruebo y dejo el campo Edad en blanco me manda a esta linea y no muestra el mensaje en otras palabras "Se detiene y me manda a esa linea"

```
int edad=Int32.Parse(txtEdad.Text);
```

Comment: Podrías agregar más código? Las líneas en sí están bien, puede que algo más esté afectando, como el scope de las variables y/o los condicionales.

Answer (score 2):

Esto sucede por que en esta instrucción

```
int edad=Int32.Parse(txtEdad.Text);
```

estas intentando convertir una cadena vacia en un número. A que numero es igual la cadena `""` adivinaste! a ninguno, por eso te lanza la excepción y el programa se rompe.

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEdad.Text))
{
  MessageBox.Show("Debes rellenar este campo");
}
else
{
  int edad=Int32.Parse(txtEdad.Text);
}
```

Y para este caso también te recomendaría hacer uso de `int.TryParse` en lugar de `int.Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

Si intentas convertir un `string` en numérico debes validar que el `string` en realidad pueda ser convertido en numérico algo que no pasa con un vacío o alfanuméricos. La mejor opción es utilizar la función `TryParse` que te devolverá un **booleano** y además si se puede convertir el `string` en número te asignara el valor a la variable.

Con este método puedes jugar con las validaciones:

```
int edad = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(txtEdad.Text, out edad))
    MessageBox.Show("Campo Edad inválido por favor ajuste y vuelva a intentar");
```